# JavaScript show/hide <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a quick, easy way to have a button which, when clicked, will show an element if it's hidden, and hide it if it's visible?

Comment: Well, yes. What have you tried? http://docs.jquery.com

Comment: 2 close vote for "Too localized"? I am puzzled, the sole fact that JQuery has a specific function for that means it is not too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your button has the (only appropriate in this case) [`id="RTM"`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) set, then just:

```
$("#RTM").click(function(){$("#some-div").toggle()});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then you could use the `toggle` method. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements

So, if you have an element with class `target`, which you want to show / hide on clicking a button (with class `toggle-btn`), then you would write something like this:

```
$('.toggle-btn').click(function() {
    $('.target').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

For instance:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){$("#divid").toggle()});
```

Comment: That won't work... you have to pass a function to `click` not a jQuery object (you are executing `$("#divid").toggle()` immediately).

Comment: Sorry :) I assumed it was just an honest mistake anyway, giving your reputation. Just wanted to point it out in case you missed it.

Comment: @Felix Kling: no problem, my bad for not double checking